# Apache (XAMPP 1.8.0) access.log/Intrusion Detection Concern

Tags: apache, logging, xampp

[I originally posted on SO but it earned me a Tumbleweed badge. This looks like a better venue for the question.]

I have Apache (XAMPP 1.8.0) running on Vista Pro x64. A couple times now I have seen a pattern like the example below in `access.log`. Concerning is the "attack" seems to somehow shift from a public IP to a valid private IP on my network (happens to be the WAN address of one of my routers).

Two questions: How is this possible, and what happens if the "attacker" stumbles on a valid request?

I've googled this to no avail.

```
177.0.X.X - - [03/Jun/2012:08:19:34 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.4/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
177.0.X.X - - [03/Jun/2012:08:19:34 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.5-rc1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
177.0.X.X - - [03/Jun/2012:08:19:34 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.2.6/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
177.0.X.X - - [03/Jun/2012:08:19:34 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.5-rc2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
192.168.15.3 - - [03/Jun/2012:08:19:56 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.6-rc2/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
177.0.X.X - - [03/Jun/2012:08:19:56 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.6-rc1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
177.0.X.X - - [03/Jun/2012:08:19:56 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.5-pl1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
192.168.15.3 - - [03/Jun/2012:08:19:59 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.7/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
192.168.15.3 - - [03/Jun/2012:08:20:01 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.7-pl1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 
192.168.15.3 - - [03/Jun/2012:08:20:02 -0400] "GET  HTTP/1.1" 400 1060 "-" "-"
```

Answer (score 2):

It may have to do with how XAMP is configured with your local server and how routing is setup to send web traffic to your server.

It's actually common to see bots scanning your server for vulnerabilities and common scripts such as phpMyAdmin.

On linux I would add them to hosts.deny, in apache you can ban them with your .htaccess file.

If the attacks are internal check your router and see who has those IP's on your network.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can pretty confidently say this is not an internal attack, and I routinely deny high-volume scan addresses in `httpd.conf`. FWIW my network architecture has two routers: Internet <-> RouterA <-> RouterB <-> many local devices. RouterA directs HTTP traffic to RouterB, which in turn directs to localhost. 192.168.15.3 is the WAN address of RouterB. Maybe RouterB is just getting confused?

Comment: Why not run a test, using a proxy or your phone for that matter going through another network connect to your website with one of the same URL's as in your log generating a 404 and see what IP shows up? A good windows program to monitor packets is WireShark formerly etherreal. Limit protocols to HTTP traffic and see what it displays in real time.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with TCP/IP protocol and HTTP but I know Nmap is capable of scanning ports with half open connections so they are harder to detect typical port scans with that. It's possible whichever scanner is doing this is sending packets just to quickly see what's there and disconnects before a full TCP connection is established and your server has no IP to log other than your local one? I don't know that sounds wrong but who knows how the connection is being created.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas and suggestions. I will try these. I had not thought of using WireShark to log traffic. I will follow-up after my tests.

Comment: Test 1: I set up WireShark to record inbound HTTP requests and as luck (?) would have it, I trapped this exact scenario from a different IP. It is interesting to look at, but doesn't answer any questions. Half-way through the hit list the source IP changes from x.x.x.x to 192.168.15.3 for no apparent reason. [continues...]

Comment: Test 2: From my phone, I bombarded my server with GET requests for phpMyAdmin. All I get in the logs is a steady stream of 203 errors, with no change in source IP, so this is inconclusive. It does occur to me though, that 192.168.15.3 is _not_ on the server's network, and Apache is set up to deny file system access in that case. None of this really answers the questions though, so I am leaving open.

Comment: (In previous comment that should be _403_ errors. Sorry about that typo.) I set up another test using a script to send 50 GET requests in rapid succession from an external network. The server log shows all originating from the external IP. IOW, I cannot replicate the source IP changing to private address 192.15.X.X. <<still mystified>>

Comment: @andyholaday are both routers setup to with DHCP so all internal machines get assigned an IP?

Comment: @andyholaday I think you may get better help on server fault i'm going to mark this to be migrated. They deal with more server configurations there.

Comment: I appreciate you sticking with me through the comments. The routers are configured with DHCP generally speaking, but in order to direct HTTP traffic to my server RouterB and the web server have fixed IPs on the LAN. The routers use port forwarding to direct HTTP traffic to the server.

Comment: Adding... Server Fault is not for **Anything in a home setting**, but my question is in a home setting.

Comment: @andyholaday people on server fault will be more familiar with your network configuration. Regardless of it being a home server or not its still relevant I feel to that site. I've gotten plenty of help on my home servers there. I also have a similar setup but with a single router forwarding HTTP, FTP, SSH, and MySQL. Actually I should bring that server online and scan my logs I know for a fact I have been scanned for phpmyadmin.